# Integrating an expression over a vector $\mathbf{w}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, machine-learning

doing my homework for a Machine Learning course, I have to calculate the following expression:

$\newcommand{\IDENTITY}{\mathbf{I}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathbf{w}}
\newcommand{\WT}{\mathbf{w}^T}
\newcommand{\PHI}{\mathbf{\phi}}
\newcommand{\PHIM}{\mathbf{\Phi}}
\newcommand{\PR}{\prod_{n=1}^N}
\newcommand{\PRM}[1]{\prod_{i=1}^M#1}
\newcommand{\PRJ}[1]{\prod_{j=1}^M#1}
\newcommand{\FRACBETA}{\frac{1}{\beta}}
\newcommand{\HALF}{\frac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathbf{t}}
\newcommand{\XM}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\IDA}{\alpha^{-1}\IDENTITY}
\newcommand{\IDB}{\beta^{-1}\IDENTITY}
\newcommand{\DETIDA}{\alpha^{-M}}
\newcommand{\DETIDB}{\beta^{-N}}
\newcommand{\LIKELIHOODCONST}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{|2\pi\IDB|}}}
\newcommand{\LIKELIHOODCONSTNICE}{
\left(\frac{\beta}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{N}{2}}
}
\newcommand{\PRIORCONST}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^M\left|\IDA\right|}}}
\newcommand{\PRIORCONSTB}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^M\DETIDA}}}
\newcommand{\PRIORCONSTNICE}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{M}{2}}}
\newcommand{\SUMWSQ}{\sum_{i=1}^M w_i^2}
\newcommand{\LOG}[1]{\mathrm{log}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\EXP}[1]{\mathrm{exp}\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\NORMAL}[1]{\mathcal{N}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\DATA}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\PROB}[1]{p\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\INTINF}[1]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\INTINFDW}[1]{\INTINF{#1}\mathrm{d}\W}
\newcommand{\INTINFDWDT}[1]{\INTINFDW{#1}\mathrm{d}\T}
\newcommand{\WTPHIEXPANDED}{\PRJ{\EXP{- w_j[\phi_n]_j)}}}
\INTINFDW{
\PR\WTPHIEXPANDED
\PRM{\EXP{-\frac{\alpha}{2}w_i^2}}}
$

Where $\PHI_n$ is a vector and $[\PHI_n]_j$ means accessing its $j$-th element.
Now, I don't know if my notation is correct, but the meaning of $\mathrm{d}\W$ is integration over all elements of $\W = (w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_M)$.

At this point my knowledge of calculus is a bit rusty. I don't know how to proceed. How do I integrate over such an arbitrary number of variables?